# Origin of once again

Tags: etymology

I'm sure that most of you will be familiar with the phrase "once again."

> Once again, I take that back.

However, I don't get the words. *Once* means "one time." However, *again* means that you did it again. Isn't this phrase an oxymoron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP is being more than a bit "literal" in seeing a conflict between **once** and **again** here.

In this context, the word **once** is largely superfluous. But if it has any significance at all, it's just an *intensifier* for **again**. It could, for example, be used repeatedly within the same discourse, applying to the *same action/statement*. This has the effect of calling attention to the repetition.

There's no implication there was only a single preceding instance - **once** just means "in the past", or "previously" there was at least one occurrence of the action, which is now being repeated **again**.

Answer (score 3):

*Once again* means "one more time."

The meaning of a phrase is not necessarily the sum of the meaning of the single words; for example, *once or twice* doesn't mean "or it's one time, or it's two times"; it means "a few times."

Set phrases do have a meaning that cannot be understood reading the meaning of the single words used in the phrase. You don't get the meaning of *man of the cloth* by looking at the meaning of *man*, *of*, and *cloth*.